# Numbers auto date on template only

Tags: numbers

Is it possible to use the `=today()` function (or something else) to insert the current date but then not update each time the file is opened?

I want to create a numbers template for my invoices. I'd like it to auto fill invoice date and date due then, when I save the document, store the values, not the function.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Insert > Date & Time.

[image: Menu]

Double-click the date and format to taste. Make sure "Automatically update on open" isn't ticked.

[image: Format]

Comment: Actually, depending on *exactly* how you plan to do this, you may want to fiddle around a bit with the Auto update setting.

Comment: hey thanks heaps just wondering do you know why insert date & time would be greyed out?

Comment: If don't have the cell selected and ready to type into you can't insert into it

Comment: yeah i know that thanks must be playing up i will try areset